# Transforming Scala varargs into Java Object... varargs

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I have a Java class that logs stuff which has a method like this:

```
void info(Object message, Object... params);
```

In Scala, I've created a wrapper around such call that looks like this:

```
def info(msg: => String, params: Any*) {
  log.info(msg, params);
}
```

When I call:

```
val host = "127.0.0.1"
val port = "1234"
info("Start on {0}:{1}", host, port)
```

I get:

```
"Started on WrappedArray(127.0.0.1, 1234):{1}"
```

Now, does anyone now how to convert params into an Object[] that can be consumed properly?

I tried to do:

```
def info(msg: => String, params: Any*)
  log.info(msg, params.toList.toArray);
}
```

But that doesn't work:

```
"Started on [Ljava.lang.Object;@14a18d:{1}"
```

Similar thing happens when you do:

```
params.asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[Object]].array
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
log.info(msg,  params.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]) : _*)
```

The following returns a Seq[AnyRef] => params.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]), and the ': _*' part tells the compiler to pass it as varargs

Result:

```
"Started on 127.0.0.1:1234"
```

Besides, this solution deals with both AnyVals and AnyRefs

Comment: May I ask you how 'info("Start on {0}:{1}", host, port)' is transformed into "Started on 127.0.0.1:1234" ? Is it your code your standard RichString ?

Comment: This is transformed by some Java code provided to me. The method that formats is called formatString in http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/infinispan/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/infinispan/util/Util.java

Answer (score 14):

*@Galder*  - there is an easier way which allows you to avoid the cumbersome `asInstanceOf[Object]` call:

```
def info(msg: => String, params: Any*) =  log.info( msg.format(params : _*) );
```

In scala 2.7, the `format(args : Any*)` function is implicitly included via `RichString` (and has a sub-optimal implementation is terms of reflection for no good reason that I can see) whereas in 2.8 the method is included via `StringLike` and is implemented via a direct call to `String.format(String, Object ...)`

I understand that the reason why Java does not contain such a method is that it has an *implication* that "every String is a format String", which is not the case. happily, I'm willing to forgo the logical correctness for the more useable class which scala provides!

Comment: This will create a the log string in any case eagerly, right?

Comment: That does not compile, it gets confused with the other version of log.info that exists. It cant differentiate between:

void info(Object message); and 
void info(Object message, Object... params);

Comment: That is news to me - it's lifted straight from my production code!

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. It doesn't compile when next to *another fragment of your code*. Not exactly worth a -1 but anyway. One suggestion would be to rename the method as logf

Comment: plus one given just to counter the stupid -1