# Difference between matching String and Int in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Consider the following two fragments of code:

```
scala> def f1(x:Any) = x match { case i:String => i; case _ => null }
f1: (x: Any)String

scala> def f2(x:Any) = x match { case i:Int => i; case _ => null }
f2: (x: Any)Any
```

Why is `f2`'s return type `Any`, while `f1`'s is `String` ? I was expecting either both to return `Any` or `f2` to return `Int`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type inference chooses the lowest common supertype if a method returns different types.

Your function `f1` returns a `String` or `null`, which common supertype is `String` because a `String` can have the value `null`. String is a subclass of `AnyRef` and `AnyRef`s can have `null` values.

Your function `f2` return an `Int` (subclass of `AnyVal`) or `null`, which common supertype is `Any`. `Int` cannot be `null`.

See http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html for Scala´s class hierarchy.

Another example:

```
scala> def f3(b: Boolean) = if (b) 42
f: (b: Boolean)AnyVal
```

`f3` returns

either 42 is `b` is `true`

or `()` if `b` is `false`.

So the types it returns are `Int` and `Unit`. The common supertype is `AnyVal`.

Comment: Is there any rationale of not allowing `Int` to be `null`? I think it would have been more convenient if `null` was also a member of `AnyVal` (or if `Int` and other primitive types were instances of `Anyref`.

Comment: I think it is because the Scala compiler uses the primitiv data type (int, double, float, ...) of the JVM to get best performance. But I know exaclty. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335319/what-are-the-relationships-between-any-anyval-anyref-object-and-how-do-they-ma

Comment: @Jus12 The `AnyVal` classes are not references, so they can't be nullified.