# Using Option[Boolean] from Java

Tags: java, scala

I've got a Scala Trait with a method that returns Option[Boolean]. I'd like to write a Java class that implements this trait. Unfortunately the compiler complains about the following code:

```
trait WithBoolean {
  def doSth(): Option[Boolean]
}

public class MyClass implements WithBoolean {
  @Override
  public Option<Boolean> doSth() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

The compile error is:

```
doSth() in MyClass cannot implement doSth() in WithBoolean
public Option<Boolean> doSth() {
                       ^
return type Option<Boolean> is not compatible with Option<Object>
```

It does compile if i change the code slightly:

```
public class MyClass implements WithBoolean {
  @Override
  public Option<Object> doSth() {  //return type has been changed to Object
    return null;
  }
}
```

But this is obviously not a nice solution. What do I need to change in order to be able to use the correct return type?

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this right now, but my best guess is that you have some `import`s mixed up, and thus try to override `Option<scala.Boolean>` with `Option<java.lang.Boolean>`.

Comment: There are no imports except for `import scala.Option;`

Comment: In that case, unqualified `Boolean` in Java code will refer to `java.lang.Boolean`, which is completely unrelated to the `scala.Boolean` in your Scala interface.

Comment: And scala.Boolean can't be used from Java, so the type Java sees _is_ Option<Object> unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Ah, right, `scala.Boolean` doesn't actually exist, because it is a [fictional class invented by the compiler](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/Boolean.scala) to give the illusion that primitive `bool` is an object.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try

```
public class MyClass implements WithBoolean {
  @Override
  public Option<? super Boolean> doSth() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3346601 Sorry to hear that :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
(value != null)?new Some<T>(value):scala.Option.apply((T) null);

(value != null)?new Some<Boolean>(value):scala.Option.apply((Boolean) null);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the class description:

> `Boolean` (equivalent to Java's `boolean` primitive type) is a subtype of [[scala.AnyVal]]. Instances of `Boolean` are not represented by an object in the underlying runtime system.

Java Boolean extends `AnyRef` (more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2335410/4419613)).
`AnyRef` and `AnyVal` both extends `Any` which is equivalent to `java.lang.Object`.
This is why only `Option<Object>` works.

If you want type safety you could do this:

```
trait WithBoolean {
  def doSth(): Option[Boolean]
}

abstract class WithBooleanForJava extends WithBoolean {

  override def doSth(): Option[Boolean] = doSthJava().map(Boolean.box(_))

  def doSthJava(): Option[java.lang.Boolean]
}
```

So you java class will look like you wanted:

```
public class MyClass extends WithBooleanForJava {

    @Override
    public Option<Boolean> doSthJava() {
        return null;
    }
}
```