# Note that Serializable extends Any, not AnyRef

Tags: scala

For the following code:

```
def foo(s: java.io.Serializable): java.lang.Object = s
```

It is compiled okay under scala 2.9.3. But got the following error under scala 2.10.4

```
scala> def foo(s: java.io.Serializable): java.lang.Object = s
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.io.Serializable
 required: Object
Note that Serializable extends Any, not AnyRef.
Such types can participate in value classes, but instances
cannot appear in singleton types or in reference comparisons.
   def foo(s: java.io.Serializable): java.lang.Object = s

                                                        ^
```

I did notice this [commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/54e284d669418ebc6445bd0ec66804b9067f6dd3) adds the "Any" to scala [Serializable](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/library/scala/Serializable.scala) trait and think it does have impact for the above error.

```
-trait Serializable extends java.io.Serializable
+trait Serializable extends Any with java.io.Serializable
```

But I am confused why this is making a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Scala 2.10, you can declare **[value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html)**, for which no instances are created, leading to less runtime overhead. Value classes are kind of the object-oriented equivalent to Java's primitive types.

Scala's type hierarchy starts with three types: The root type `Any` and its two distinct children `AnyVal` and `AnyRef`. Until Scala 2.9, `AnyVal` could not be extended. `AnyRef` is equivalent to `java.lang.Object`. For reference: [What are the relationships between Any, AnyVal, AnyRef, Object and how do they map when used in Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335319/what-are-the-relationships-between-any-anyval-anyref-object-and-how-do-they-m)

From the Scala language specification:

> The extends clause "extends sc with mt_1 with ... with mt_m" can be
>   omitted, in which case "extends scala.AnyRef" is assumed.

**Edit2:** While this quote does not apply directly to the example (the extends-clause is not empty), we can be quite confident that there is no implicit inheritance of `Any`. Furthermore, `java.io.Serializable` surely does not inherit `Any`.

#### Conclusion

By explicitely extending `Any`, a class that implements `Serializable` can now also be a value class. This seems to make sense, as you may want to serialize your custom value classes. However, this means that an instance of `Serializable` is now not guaranteed to extend `AnyRef`, and therefore may not be compatible with `java.lang.Object`.

**Edit:**

#### Short answer:

```
Serializable extends java.io.Serializable
```

is equal to

```
Serializable extends AnyRef with java.io.Serializable
```

which is not equal to

```
Serializable extends Any with java.io.Serializable
```