# How to create a new AnyRef?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I have a JSON object and part of it I am mapping to AnyRef due to the fact that it might contain the variable key/value pairs.  I treat that section as junk drawer. But I have to add "id" and random key to that AnyRef object.  How can I do that?

I have tried to do the following but the map is stored and the generated JSON does not look right.

Here is my example:

```
val map1 = requestStateChange.cloudModel.asInstanceOf[Option[Map[String, AnyRef]]]
val newModel = List(("id", java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString)).toMap[String, AnyRef] ++ map1.get
```

What I really want to have generates is something like this:

```
{   
  "model": {
    "id": "c9725317-e2e5-43e8-876e-5ab6a16b951d"
    "version": "v1",
    "location": "...",
    "type": "...",
    "data": {
        "id": "9520146"
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel here.  As a rule of thumb, idiomatic Scala avoids using types like `Any` when possible.  There are plenty of libraries that let you deal with JSON easily.  You might consider Play JSON.  If you were using that library, you could do something like:

```
val myJsonString = """{ "foo" : "bar" }"""
val map = Json.parse(myJsonString).as[JsObject]
val newMap = map + ("id" -> JsNumber(123)) //Adding a new property is easy now
Json.stringify(newMap) // {"foo":"bar","id":123}, as desired
```

You can read more about Play JSON [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson).  You can read about other alternative to Play JSON [here](http://engineering.ooyala.com/blog/comparing-scala-json-libraries).

If you do need to instantiate an `AnyRef`, you can assign any type to an `AnyRef` except the basic value types:

```
Map(1 -> "a") : AnyRef
```

You might consider using `Any` instead of `AnyRef`, which is even more general, and will allow you to use basic value types as well, such as `1 : Any`.  You can read more about the relationship between `Any`, `AnyRef`, and `AnyVal` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335319/what-are-the-relationships-between-any-anyval-anyref-object-and-how-do-they-m).  For your example, you could do something like this:

```
val map1 : Map[String, Any] = Map("model" -> Map("version" -> "v1"))
val model = map1("model").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
val newModel = model.updated("id", 123)
val newMap = map1.updated("model", newModel)
```