# Interpret Scala syntax for varargs

Tags: scala, syntax, variadic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax sugar: _*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176440/syntax-sugar)

I wrote a function that gets passed a format string (for String.format(...)) and a varargs array of parameters (among other things). The method looks like this:

```
def myMethod(foo: Number, formatStr: String, params: Any*): Unit = {
  // .. some stuff with foo
  println(formatStr, params.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]) : _*)
}
```

I got the syntax for the params argument [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334200). It works! But how? I do not understand the syntax of the second argument to `println`, particularly the ending part (`: _*`). It is obviously calling `map` and expanding the array to a sequence of `AnyRef`s.

Comment: @Kevin: I concur. I voted to close my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally, the `:` notation is used for type ascription, forcing the compiler to see a value as some particular type.  This is not *quite* the same as casting.

```
val b = 1 : Byte
val f = 1 : Float
val d = 1 : Double
```

In this case, you're ascribing the special *varargs* type `_*`.  This mirrors the asterisk notation used for declaring a varargs parameter and can be used on a variable of any type that subclasses `Seq[T]`:

```
def myMethod(params: Any*) = ... //varargs parameter, use as an Array[Any]

val list = Seq("a", 42, 3.14) //a Seq[Any]
myMethod(list : _*)
```

Answer (score 7):

The ending part `: _*` converts a collection into vararg parameters.

It looks weird, I know.