# Convert Scala Any to Java Object

Tags: java, scala, reflection, scala-java-interop

I've a problem using Java Reflection from Scala. My Code:

```
case class MyClass(id: String, value: Double)     

def create(values: Map[String, Any]): MyClass = {
   val constructor = classOf[MyClass].getConstructors.head
   val arguments = classOf[MyClass].getDeclaredFields().map( f => values(f.getName) )
   constructor.newInstance(arguments: _*).asInstanceOf[MyClass]
} 

create(Map("id" -> "CE0D23A", "value" -> 828.32))
```

My problem is, that I need to pass a Map[String, Any], because one of the values is a Double, but newInstance needs Object, not Any.

I tried the same with scalas universe:

```
case class MyClass(id: String, value: Double)     

def create(values: Map[String, Any]): MyClass = {
   val m = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
   val myClass = universe.typeOf[MyClass].typeSymbol.asClass
   val cm = m.reflectClass(myClass)
   val ctro = universe.typeOf[MyClass].declaration(universe.nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
   val ctorm = cm.reflectConstructor(ctro)
   ctorm(values: _*).asInstanceOf[MyClass]
} 

create(Map("id" -> "CE0D23A", "value" -> 828.32))
```

Problem here is, that I only introduced MyClass for the example. Later it should be a generic function like `def create(values: Map[String, Any]): T`. But then I got the following exception: "No TypeTag available for T"

Is there any way to transform these values?

Thank you

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`java.lang.Object` is equivalent to `AnyRef` in Scala, not `Any`. The idea is, Scala `Double` (roughly equivalent to Java `double`) is an `Any`, but not an `AnyRef`. `java.lang.Double` is an `AnyRef`, thus also an `Any`.

You can simply cast an `Any` to `AnyRef`, which will perform the needed conversion to turn a Scala `Double` into a `java.lang.Double`:

```
scala> val x = 3.5
x: Double = 3.5

scala> x.getClass
res0: Class[Double] = double

scala> val y = x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
y: AnyRef = 3.5

scala> y.getClass
res1: Class[_ <: AnyRef] = class java.lang.Double
```

Comment: I added a second exampled based on scalas universe. Maybe you know a solution for this problem too? Or is there no way to use scalas universe runtime reflection with generics?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry. Maybe you should post it as a new, separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was a bit late but here goes:

The following works:

```
constructor.newInstance(arguments.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]: _*).asInstanceOf[MyClass]
```

See also: [Transforming Scala varargs into Java Object... varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334200/transforming-scala-varargs-into-java-object-varargs)

Advice: I'd be very cautious using reflection. In Scala that is bad style. One way to limit/encapsulate it could be:

```
case class MyClass(id: String, value: Double)     

object MyClass {

    import scala.util.Try
    def apply(map: Map[String, Any] /* this is asking for trouble */) : Option[MyClass]  =  for {
            id <- maybeT[String](map.get("id"))
            value <- maybeT[Double](map.get("value"))
        } yield MyClass(id, value)

    // a truly global utility?
    @inline def maybeT[T] ( a: Any /*Option[T]*/ ) : Option[T]= Try(a.asInstanceOf[Option[T]]).toOption.flatten //yep ugly as hell

}


MyClass(Map("id" -> "CE0D23A", "value" -> 828.32))
```