# Calling Java method that receive variable amount of parameters from Scala

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I am trying to wrap a Java method that receives variable amount of parameters, example:

```
void info(String var1, Object... var2);
```

I used the following:

```
def info(message: String, any: Any*): Unit = {
   LOGGER.info(message, any)
}
```

But that doesn't work, it ends up calling an info that receives only 1 object:

```
void info(String var1, Object var2);
```

How can I solve this to call the java method that receives multiple parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334200/transforming-scala-varargs-into-java-object-varargs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
def info(message: String, any: Any*): Unit = {
  LOGGER.info(message, any.asInstanceOf[Seq[Object]]: _*)
}
```

or

```
def info(message: String, any: AnyRef*): Unit = {
  LOGGER.info(message, any: _*)
}
```

without casting but not applicable to primitive types.

Comment: The first works, but the second doesn't. Could it be that AnyRef doesn't have the primitives for Int? I found that here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html

Comment: @FedeE. I wrote that the second wouldn't work for primitive types like `Int`.